# Query to order by specific item to be first and then to sort the rest with id desc

Tags: 8, entities

I am into a unique requirement where I need to sort records to show specific data first and then rest sort by id descending.
I am able to see records using `SELECT * FROM jobs where type='jobs' and status=1 order by field_job_id='J5-00104' desc,field_job_id desc;`.

Is there any way to achieve this in Drupal way?
BTW I am trying to manipulate a query with the following code.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'jobs');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->sort('field_job_id="J5-00104"', 'DESC');
$query->sort('field_job_id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: There are several ways I can think of, but maybe the fastest one would be to make 2 queries - one with the specific item that should float on top and then create a second request, ignoring this specific item. Then combine the two results and you'd be done. For sure there are better 'Drupal' ways, but they would require a bit more time and work. One of them would be to add a flag to this entity type and sort by it. Something like 'promoted' for example.

Comment: I would add a field to the items flagging the item that should be listed first. Then set the order to be first on 'flagged'.